# How to use pure C++ code with IL2CPP for Unity compilation into windows application?

Tags: c#, c++, windows, unity-game-engine, il2cpp

I want to have a crossplatform application (including browser integration). I have C++ library\algorithms I want to use in form of sources (to make Unity compile it on each platform). I know it could work if I use Mac or WebGL as primary build targets. Yet I have windows as my primary user base. So I want to use IL2CPP on windows to compile my C# and C++ code.

How to structure project and set IL2CPP to compile C++ files in unity on windows in order to create windows executable?

Comment: Forget it and rewrite your algorithms in ordinary c#.

Answer (score 1):

You can talk with C or C++ (and others depending on your target platforms) libraries using [Native Plugins](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/NativePlugins.html). It is even possible to use to [call C++ function from a plugin](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-interactingwithbrowserscripting.html) using WebGL thanks to emscripten compilation.

Note that it has nothing to do with IL2CPP. IL stands for Intermediate Language (IL), the low-level output from .NET compilers. Your C++ code will be compiled directly to machine code/ASM code and will be called from within your script code. Your script will either be running on the Mono virtual machine or using IL2CPP (depending on the platform).

Comment: More on IL2CPP internals on [this Unity blog post](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2015/05/06/an-introduction-to-ilcpp-internals/).

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible now, as Unity does not support IL2CPP as a scripting backend for the Windows standalone target.